# How can I use Ms Access Date/Time Extended data type

Tags: datetime, ms-access, types

Ms Access [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-the-date-time-extended-data-type-708c32da-a052-4cc2-9850-9851042e0024?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) suggests there is a data type called "Date/Time Extended" which:

> The Date/Time Extended data type stores date and time information and is similar to the Date/Time data type, but it provides a larger date range, a higher fractional precision, and compatibility with the SQL Server datetime2 date type.

However I cannot select this as the option is not in the table design Data Type drop/down list.

My version is Microsoft Access for Microsoft 365 (16.0.12827.20328) 64-Bit.

How can I use the "Date/Time Extended" data type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems it was released in May see [Office Insider Monthly (Targeted) v2005 build 12827.20210 - May 21](https://www.tenforums.com/windows-10-news/156817-office-insider-monthly-targeted-v2005-build-12827-20210-may-21-a.html).

But you have to enable it in [Options](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/set-user-options-for-the-current-database-29b6b7be-4c3b-43a7-b8f0-5e1c68f5adce#__toc309288145) first.

As of today it should be availible on all channels except [Semi-Annual Enterprise Channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/semi-annual-enterprise-channel).

To get your general release number (starts with 200X), check Word for Office Version.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, Date/Time Extended is not yet available in the latest release builds.

The documentation seems to be ahead of the actual release.

If you need it regardless, go to the *Account* page, and sign up for Office Insider, the beta channel, then click update options, and Update Now.

After that, it's in the dropdown for field types. Note that using it will break compatibility with previous versions of Office.

I can currently use the Date/Time Extended data type, and am on version 16.0.13012.20000 (latest beta channel).

Note that I strongly recommend on refraining from using this type for other purposes than testing until it's in a release version and you're 100% sure everyone using the database you intend to use it in has updated to a version that allows it.

Comment: Note as well, that there is no support for this datatype in VBA, neither plans for providing it, not even a simple conversion option between it and DateTime. Thus, as seen in the example on the doc side, values must be handled as strings.

Comment: The docs are relatively optimistic, as it seems to be stored as an ASCII string containing only numbers and colons in a format that separates days, seconds, and I think milliseconds but unclear on the last term by colons, starting from `1-1-1 00:00:00`. This makes constructing and parsing these DateTime Extended objects relatively hard for novice programmers (this is still beta, though).

Comment: Sure, I just wanted to kill any hope, that "this version, SQL, next version also VBA support". Its main purpose is to be able to query an SQL Server table directly without erroring on values like _9999-12-31-23:59:59.9999999_ (used by some for "unknown future date") which should convert to DateTime _10000-01-01 00:00:00_ but can't, as that is outside the range of DateTime; the maximum usable value for DateTime is _9999-12-31 23:59:59.999_.

Comment: @ErikA Yes it looks like it was added in the Current Channel (Preview) Version 2005: June 04 (Build 12827.20320) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/current-channel-preview#feature-updates-2. Hopefully it will be released to current channel soon.