# Access table showing incorrect data from a linked table

Tags: postgresql, ms-access, odbc

I have an issue with my access table which is linked from postgres. The table in postgres has a time column with a 'time without time zone' data type and it looks fine. However when i linked the table to Access, the same fields show the same data but have a date in front of them. It looks like this, '07/01/2023 11:33:00 AM'. I just want it to display time.

I have tried chaning the data type in postgres and relinking the table but that didnt help. I've deleted the table and created a new one and that didnt help. Whenever I try to delete the dates directly from the table in access I get an error 'Another user edited this record and saved the changes before you attempted to save your changes' and it goes back to how it was.

Comment: To your question add the answers to: 1) What is the data type in the Access table? 2) What is the `time` value in the Postgres table? The delete issue is due to the [FAQ](https://odbc.postgresql.org/faq.html#6.4) *...This record has been changed by another user since you started editing it...*. Basically it means you cannot have `time\timestamps` in Access with fractional seconds.

Comment: I have SQLServer table with a Time field type. In Access it shows up as Text. That was the only way I could get time to show automatically without date portion. If nothing similar in postgreSQL, can set format in Access textbox to not show date part but it is still stored in data. Also, can use TimeValue() function to extract time part.

Comment: Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62464046/how-can-i-use-ms-access-date-time-extended-data-type#:~:text=Ms%20Access%20documentation%20suggests%20there%20is%20a%20data,compatibility%20with%20the%20SQL%20Server%20datetime2%20date%20type.